# How protein denaturation affects digestion?

Tags: proteins, digestive-system, digestion

Which one of these is a) easier to digest, b) more nutritious (in whatever sense):
1. scrambled egg,
2. raw egg.

Bascially is "denatured protein are worse than not denatured" a myth, or not?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://jn.nutrition.org/content/128/10/1716.full) article specifically looks at the question you're asking.  Just jump down to the conclusion if it's too technical.

To summarize, cooking the egg (or heat pre-treatment as they call it in the paper) leads to a significant increase in protein uptake.

I'd call that myth busted via radiolabeling.

Comment: For some proteins denaturation can make them insoluble. This is not so in the case of egg albumin though.